# Calculate LC50 from a non-sigmoid dose response curve

Tags: r, sigmoid-curve, dose-response

[image]

Is it possible to calculate LC50 (concentration that is lethal for 50% of the test organisms), when my dataset does not have a sigmoid dose response curve?

For my experiment, I had 6 treatments exposing invertebrates to a pesticide (control + five concentrations). The mortality for the test animals increased with the first two concentrations, but then the mortality is lower for the next higher concentration before it increases a little bit again. So the response increases before it flattens out at about 40-50% mortality. This might be due to the animals avoiding their spiked feed at the higher concentrations, then reducing their exposure and thus mortality.

I use the R software. I have tried to fit log-logistic dose response curves using the drc package (and all other models that the package contains), and no models get a good fit. I have also tried to calculate LC50 using the ecotoxicology package, no luck, and tried the trimmed Spearman-Karber method, which didn´t work either.

I believe this is because of the non-sigmoid curve. Are there any other things I can try in order to calculate this?

One option is just to present the data without LC50 value, but I want to try all options.

Comment: If you list data people may be able to answer.

Comment: If the true curve indeed has this complex hormetic shape, then the LC50 might not even be defined.  The most practical solution might be to define the LC50 as the *smallest* dose at which the mortality rate is 50%.

Comment: Sorry @Carl, I have added a plot of my datapoints, you can see that the mortality increases before it sort of flattens.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @whuber and your practical suggestion, I might just go for an approach like that.

Comment: It seems to me that you 1) have significant noise in the data and 2) haven't explored higher concentrations of your pesticide. What if you went up to 1000 or 1e6 (in whatever units that might be) with your concentration? I find it hard to imagine that the curve is not approximately sigmoid, at the appropriate scale: Physically, it should approach $0$ as log-concentration goes towards $- \infty$ and $1$ as it goes towards $+ \infty$. What else could it do? Oscillate?

Comment: Yes, you should indeed go to higher dose levels i your experiments! (Lykke til med det) And think about why there is so much noise. There is no way you can conclude te curve is non-monotonic base on that graph!

Comment: Thanks so much for the feedback. I have conducted an experiment that had higher concentrations, where 1 mg/kg dry soil gave a 100% mortality from the pesticide. But, in this experiment, the animals were presented with spiked feed, instead of their surrounding environment, which they cannot avoid. So I think increasing the concentrations would not necessarily increase the mortality as the exposure does not increase if the animals avoid their feed. 

But I get your point :)

Comment: The plot is helpful.  It shows you do *not* have a curve of the type you describe.  A "sigmoid" will fit these data well, but (a) you have to use an appropriate fitting procedure and (b) you will need to choose the right functional form. I notice you have extremely low mortalities (all under 0.8%), which makes it impossible to estimate an LC50 anyway.  But supposing your vertical axis is not in % but in actual values, could you indicate *how many* subjects are in each group?  This is crucial.

Comment: @whuber, thanks for your reply. There is a mistake on the y-axis, sorry, it is proportions, so the mortality is lower than 80%, not 0.8%. 

My datapoints consist of one box with 20 animals, so it is proportions of the animals in each container that survived. But I have these values, and have included these when Have tried to fit a model. 

Ok, I have not managed the. fit. Do you have any tips on where I can read about different fitting procedures, perhaps? Thank you :)

Comment: You would do this with a mixed binomial GLM.  You need one random term for deviations between mortality and the sigmoid and another for variations within each fixed dose.  It would be interesting to investigate why that is; one possible explanation is that the doses were not accurately measured, but there are many others.

Comment: Yes, I will give glmm a go, thanks so much, @whuber! 
I would assume it is because some animals ate more "toxic food" than others, but yeah, the variation is an issue. Thanks for the help!